# fabrics not sending crash report

Tags: android

using fabrics in Android to send crash report. Used `throw RuntimeException("This is a crash");` on `OnCreate` of MainActivity. The crash report is uploaded else if it is used inside button click listener or any other acitivity oncreate, it is not uploading crash report. This is

```
  @Override   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
}
```

**Gradle version** 4.4
**Android plugin version** 3.1.4

**Manifest**

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="firebase_analytics_collection_enabled"
        android:value="false" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="5c23f20ffeaecaa62e433c9b6229b1b40fb8a483"
        />
```

**app level gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
//    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.first"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 45
        versionName "2.1.6"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro', 'proguard-fresco.pro'


        }
    }

    configurations {
        all {
            exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.4.9'
    implementation "com.razorpay:razorpay-java:1.3.8"

    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.16.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.9.0'
//    implementation 'com.github.freshdesk:hotline-android:1.2.3'
    implementation 'com.github.freshdesk:freshchat-android:1.5.2'


//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.18.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.0'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**project level gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
//        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: please ad main activity code

Comment: did u initialize fabric

Comment: Yup, initialized the fabrics

Comment: ad also manifest code and gradle

Comment: when the app is crashed immediately after it starts in onCreate method, the crash report being uploaded, but when it crshed else where on button click listener or on any other activity's onCreate the report is not sent

Comment: posted answer its work for me recently tried

Comment: remove the implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.0'

Comment: Solution: I have used default thread for each fragment, that the reason it doesn't upload the crash report. Pls Comment this line `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler(getActivity()));`

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        throw new RuntimeException("This is a crash");
    }
```

> Manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="4*************************" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

> Build Gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> Gradel Module App

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


android {
    ........
    ........
}

dependencies {
    ........
    ........

    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

## Cause a Test Crash

You can check to see whether crash reporting has successfully been added simply by throwing an uncaught exception, e.g.:

```
throw new RuntimeException("This is a crash");
```

Crashes are sent from your app after it’s been reopened, so be sure to place this line outside your Application class, or the onCreate() method of your launch Activity; adding a button to trigger the crash often works very well.

We process crashes in real-time. If we detect that a crash is due to a new issue, it will show up as a new issue on your dashboard. If it’s a reoccurrence of an existing issue, that issue’s crash counter will be incremented and the information from the new crash will be included into the issue.

## Troubleshooting

If you’re not seeing crashes, check the following common causes of delays:

1. Make sure our SDK initialization line is after all other 3rd-party
   SDKs
2. Force a crash and then relaunch the app.
3. If you’re using our `Crashlytics.getInstance().crash()` method for
   testing purposes, make sure it’s not in the onCreate method of your
   launch Activity
4. Check your network connection to be sure that it’s stable and able
   to send up crashes. Keep in mind that exceptions are not guaranteed
   to cause a crash. The full code path, including code in system
   libraries matters here. Devices and emulators and different OSes
   will have different behaviors regarding which types of errors
   actually cause crashes, especially when the UI thread is involved.

Comment: when crashed "throw new RuntimeException("This is a crash");" onCreate the report gets uploaded  but on button clicklistener or elsewhere it fails.

Comment: Add tried initializing fabrics in splashscreen, the same thing happens.

Comment: I think fabrics does its job sends report only after app crashed, In this scenario, this app is not closing immidiately. After the crash the ui becomes unresponse for 5 seconds. After that it is asking to close app, what is wrong with the app? threading ....

Comment: After the crash the ui becomes unresponse for 5 seconds. may be because of internet speed